# Can I make all the keys work on a Logitech N305 keypad

Tags: keyboard, logitech

I'm using a Logitech N305 key pad with ubuntu 14.04 and it mostly works but the keys for =() and the 3 function keys seem to return multiple or unhelpful keystrokes. Is there a way to make them return =() or some useful function.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the solution here :

http://users.skynet.be/linux-rixensart/3_peripheriques.html#keypad